# Convert integer to Base 64 value

Tags: c#, int, type-conversion

I have an integer value. I want to convert it to the Base 64 value. I tried the following code.

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(123);
string str = Convert.ToBase64String(b);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Its giving the out put as `"ewAAAA=="` with 8 characters.
I convert the same value to base 16 as follows

```
int decvalue = 123;
string hex = decvalue.ToString("X");
Console.WriteLine(hex);
```

the out put of the previous code is 7B
If we do this in maths the out comes are same. How its differ? How can I get same value to Base 64 as well. (I found the above base 64 conversion in the internet)

Comment: Base 64 and hex (base 16) are different representations. Why did you expect the same Output?

Comment: For example if we convert "10" in base to hexadecimal its "A". if we use base 64 (in mathematics way) its "10". I want to get that out come.

Comment: @udaya726 yeah, that's base-64 **arithmetic**; `Convert` is base-64 **encoding** - very different

Comment: I edited my answer to provide a comparable base-64 convert; gives `B7`, which sounds right: `B` (==1)*64 + `7` (==59) ==> 123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is rather unclear... "How is it differ?" - well, in many different ways:

- one is base-16, the other is base-64 (hence they are fundamentally different *anyway*)
- one is doing an arithmetic representation; one is a byte serialization format - very different
- one is using little-endian arithmetic (assuming a standard CPU), the other is using big-endian arithmetic

To get a **comparable** base-64 result, you probably need to code it manually (since `Convert` only support base-8, base-10, base-16 for arithmetic converts). Perhaps (note: not optimized):

```
static void Main()
{
    string b64 = ConvertToBase64Arithmetic(123);

}


// uint because I don't care to worry about sign
static string ConvertToBase64Arithmetic(uint i)
{
    const string alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    do
    {
        sb.Insert(0, alphabet[(int)(i % 64)]);
        i = i / 64;
    } while (i != 0);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```